# How to make a grid shrink and grow to fit canvas size when changed in P5.js?

Tags: p5.js

this in my first post. I am new to coding and have been experimenting with different languages. I am in the early learning stages with P5 and am struggling to figure something out. I am using Takawo's code from openprocessing.org as inspiration and have a couple of questions.

Here is the sample code I am working from: [openprocessing.org/sketch/1009891](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1009891)

As you notice on the 800x800 canvas the design shrinks and grows to fit the number of columns and rows with each randomly generated canvas but, this appears to only work on a square canvas.

How would I get it to behave the same way even if the canvas was changed to lets say 2400p x 3000px (8"x10")? Basically so it fills a page with the randomly generated (evenly spaced) design.

It seems to work okay but not great for the width (it cuts off part of it sometimes) but the height always ends up with a big empty area at the bottom.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions. Like I said, I am pretty new to p5 and coding in general.

Here is the sample code of Takaow's that I am playing with:   https://editor.p5js.org/Rico2022/sketches/jLZCnxs4x

```js
let url = "https://coolors.co/006d77-83c5be-edf6f9-ffddd2-e29578";
let palette;
let c = -1;
let pc = c;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800);
    colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100, 100);
    angleMode(DEGREES);
    noSmooth();

    palette = createPalette(url);
}

function draw() {
    background(0, 0, 95);
    drawingContext.shadowColor = color(0, 0, 0, 5);
    drawingContext.shadowBlur = width / 20;

    let cell_num = int(random(2, 6));

    for (let i = 0; i < cell_num; i++) {

        let cells = cell_num * cell_num - i * cell_num;
        let offset = width / 20;
        let margin = offset / 3;
        let d = (width - offset * 2 - margin * (cells - 1)) / cells;
        let numMax = 4;
        let num_arr = [];

        for (let j = 0; j < cells; j++) {
            num_arr[j] = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
                let neighbor = [];
                if (i != 0) neighbor.push(num_arr[j][i - 1]);
                if (j != 0) neighbor.push(num_arr[j - 1][i]);
                let n = int(random(numMax));
                while (n == neighbor[0] || n == neighbor[1]) n = int(random(numMax));
                num_arr[j][i] = n;
            }
        }
        for (let j = 0; j < cells; j++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
                let x = offset + i * (d + margin);
                let y = offset + j * (d + margin);
                // rect(x, y, d, d);
                push();
                translate(x + d / 2, y + d / 2);
                rotate(num_arr[j][i] * 360 / 4);
                translate(-d / 2, -d / 2);
                // arc(0, 0, d * 2, d * 2, 0, 90);
                let sep = random([2, 4, 8]);
                if (random(100) > 50) {
                    for (let e = d; e > 0; e -= d / sep) {
                        push();
                        noStroke();
                        // fill(0, 0, 100);
                        while (c == pc) c = random(palette);
                        pc = c;
                        fill(c);
                        triangle(e, 0, 0, e, 0, 0);
                        pop();
                        // line(e, 0, 0, e);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (let e = d; e > 0; e -= d / sep) {
                        while (c == pc) c = random(palette);
                        pc = c;
                        fill(c);
                        noStroke();
                        arc(0, 0, e * 2, e * 2, 0, 90);
                    }

                }
                pop();

            }
        }
    }
    // let g = get();
    // clear();
    // background(0, 0, 90);
    // image(g, 0, 0);
    // noLoop();
    frameRate(0.5);
}

function createPalette(_url) {
    let slash_index = _url.lastIndexOf('/');
    let pallate_str = _url.slice(slash_index + 1);
    let arr = pallate_str.split('-');
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = color('#' + arr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's a really cool design!  It's definitely expecting a square canvas because there is no mention of `height` anywhere, only `width`, so it's not a trivial one-line change.  I find this code very hard to read because these variables do not have descriptive names.  Not an easy one for me to answer.

Comment: The `i` and `j` nested loops seem to represent `x` and `y`.  If you want to have a height that's different than the width then they wouldn't both use `< cells`.  But we want each box to be square.  I'm still working this out.

Comment: Hmm. Now I'm realizing that there's a more fundamental problem, because a rectangular canvas is not going to be able to be divided into multiple different grids of squares.  Like 2400px x 3000px is 4x5 which is good, but it's 2x2.5, 3x3.75, 5x6.25 so you would have to have some squares be cut off on those tilings.

Comment: Hi Linda, Thank you for your reply. I have been racking my brain and picking apart the code. You're absolutely right that the names are as vague as can be. Also it is tied to the use of cells. I've been tinkering and researching other ways to implement it. So far I am stuck though. In my mind, what I want to do  seems like it should be pretty easy. But in reality it seems far more than advanced than I am... Going to keep at it and will keep asking. Someone has had to of of wanted the accomplish the same thing.